# Element not located BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the overview part on the webpage. But in return I am getting an empty list. Where am I making a mistake? I tried the same with Selenium, it displays an error:

> no such element: Unable to locate element

My code. It returns title and description but not the overview.

```
def next_page(link):
    page_response = requests.get('https://www.nilfisk.com/'+link, headers=headers)
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text, 'html.parser')

    title = page_soup.select_one('h1.product__name-container').text
    description = page_soup.select_one('#productContentDescriptionContainerId p').text
    print(title, ': ', description)

    overview = page_soup.find_all('div', class_='inner-html')
    print(title, ': ', str(overview))


def main():
    url = 'https://www.nilfisk.com/en-au/search/?q=13300148'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    product = soup.select_one('div.sitesearchresult__row div.col-8 a').attrs['href']
    next_page(product)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: When you navigate the soup *by-hand* can you tell what went wrong? You should always include an example of the data with your [mre]

Comment: What do you mean with overview part? Please improve your question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is rendered dynamically by `javascript`, so you have to use `selenium` and `waits` or could extract it from the `<script>` while converting string to JSON and pick by key:

```
description = BeautifulSoup(json.loads('{'+page_soup.select_one('[id^="ProductDescription"] + script').text.split('\',{')[-1].split(',true')[0])['descriptionContent']).text
```

*Because OP is missing details and expected output, this is just pointing in a direction.*

##### Example

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def next_page(link):
    page_response = requests.get('https://www.nilfisk.com'+link)
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text, 'html.parser')

    title = page_soup.select_one('h1.product__name-container').text
    description = BeautifulSoup(json.loads('{'+page_soup.select_one('[id^="ProductDescription"] + script').text.split('\',{')[-1].split(',true')[0])['descriptionContent']).text
    print(title, ': ', description)

def main():
    url = 'https://www.nilfisk.com/en-au/search/?q=13300148'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    product = soup.select_one('div.sitesearchresult__row div.col-8 a').attrs['href']
    next_page(product)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

###### Output

```
SR1601 D Maxi :  
 SR1601 is claimed to be the most technically advanced sweeper in its category, with innovations that increase cleaning productivity whilst simplifying operating and servicing requirements. Designed for industrial applications such as heavily soiled factories, construction sites, car parks etc

 The dust control is outstanding and unbeatable in the industry. The DustGuardTM system further reduces airborne particles. Less dust means less cleaning elsewhere. The productivity is excellent, thanks to a huge 900 mm main broom, a 1600 mm wide sweeping path, and all around reliability for getting the job done quickly and efficiently.

 Available in Diesel, LPG and Battery Models.
```

Comment: how will be expression to get the 'Specifications ' tab? I tried this but didn't work:
```
spec = BeautifulSoup(json.loads(
        '{' + page_soup.select_one('[id^="ProductSpecificationsTab"] + script').text.split('\',{')[-1].split(',true')[0])[
                                    'specificationElements'])
```

Comment: It is the same pattern, but you have to be aware that it do not contains HTML (no conversion to beautifoulsoup object needed) instead a `list` of `dicts` -- `json.loads('{'+page_soup.select_one('[id^="ProductSpecific"] + script').text.split('\',{')[-1].split(',true')[0])['specificationElements']`